# Django sendfile download -- Page not found

Tags: python, django, download

I'm using the Django sendfile module to serve files to the user. Docs:

https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile

I used the simple backend. More precisely, I put `SENDFILE_BACKEND = 'sendfile.backends.simple'` in my `settings.py`.

I have checked and doucle-checked that the files are there. This is my code (I think only the request function is relevant but I'm including the whole function because I use `pk` in `urls.py`):

```
def permit(request, pk)
    if int(request.user.id) == int(pk) and int(request.user.id) >= 1:
        return sendfile(request, request.path)
    else:
        return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/notendur/list')
```

`user` is a Django `User` object. `pk` is the regular expression taken from `urls.py`.
And the error I get is

```
404: [path to file] does not exist.
```

This is the relevant entry in `project/urls.py`:

```
url(r'^media/uploads/(?P<pk>[^/]+)', 'notendur.views.permit')
```

As you can see, the `urls.py` redirects the user to the `permit` function if the regx matches. If the user's ID is equal to the directory name (I name the directories by user ID) then the user is allowed to download the file, otherwise not.

I have confirmed that this error is due to the sendfile module because the download works fine if I serve the file directly, without the sendfile module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly a big warning, what you are doing is dangerous. You are trusting your user to give you a path. You must always sanitize this!

Now to your issue: rather than giving a relative file to the current directory, it is better practice to give an absolute file based on some root media path set in your settings file then do:

```
sanitized_path = sanitize(request.path) # you'll have to write a sanitize function
media_path = "%s%s" (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, sanitized_path)
if not path.exists(media_path): # Don't trust your visitors too much!
   # raise 404
return sendfile(request, media_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How could my function be exploited?

Comment: Let's say your user sends you the path ../../../../(PATH_TO_SENSITIVE_DATA), your function will happily return it.

Comment: But the urls.py file takes care of that, right? The user can only navigate where the urls.py allows him to?

Comment: Hmm, no you are correct. I can navigate freely within the media folder!